# Change shape and color of geom points in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the issue, the following code is changing the color of the data points but not the shape. What is wrong?

```
g <- ggplot(mydata, aes(var1, var2)
g <- g + geom_point(aes(shape=var3, color=var3), shape=1)
g <- g + facet_grid(.~var4)
g <- g + theme(legend.position="bottom") + guides(colour = guide_legend(ncol = 1))
```

Comment: You have 2 times the argument `shape` once within `aes()` and once outside.Remove the one outside... Please also provide a reproducible example for any question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. Why do you have two `shape`s?
Replace

```
geom_point(aes(shape=var3, color=var3), shape=1)
```

With

```
geom_point(aes(shape=var3, color=var3)
```

And this is how I would write it:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydata, aes(var1, var2) +
    geom_point(aes(shape = var3, color = var3)) +
    facet_grid(. ~ var4) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
    guides(colour = guide_legend(ncol = 1))
```